# How does one obtain connectors for game controllers to put on a PCB if e.g our design takes input from a PS1 Dual-Shock controller?

Tags: pcb, connector

It is quite possible that one decides to design a device that can take input from a (wired) game controller like the NES, SNES, PS1, PS2 controllers which are going to have their own protocol. For a PS2 dual shock controller, designing something that can decode the protocol is a project in itself.

However, always there is a problem of where to get a connector for the "consolve side" of the controller connection. When the game console was manufactuered, they put in a connector on the front. However, if I want my own design project to take input from e.g a PS2 dual shock controller, how do I get the "female" connetor that shall go onto the PCB? Any ideas?

One possibility is to design a connector and print it using a 3D printer, that however is a project in itself and it still needs to be considered how the metal contacts will be put in.

Comment: Almost certainly those connectors are custom, and not something you can buy anywhere, especially years later. 3D printing may be your best option there.

Comment: Certainly some third parties must be producing them right?

Comment: Why would they? Who's buying them other than a handful of hackers?

Comment: Depending on how many you need, you might be able to find some broken gaming consoles on eBay (or wherever) and salvage the connectors...

Comment: (1) Cut the original plug from the end of the controller's cable.  Re-terminate the cable with your own non-prorietary plug, for which you can buy a jack.  (or 2) Cannibalize the jacks from decommissioned gaming consoles.

Comment: Depends on the quantity. For a one or two off project, cannibalize a PS2 multitap. For small quantities, look at ebay for repair parts. For larger, look at direct Chinese or Japanese suppliers on sites like alibaba or ali express or I forget the name of the other one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done exactly that for a university project. I wanted to interface to a NES controller, so I had to find some connectors. I ended up buying a splitter adaptor, which gave me four connectors to play with. I then measured the dimensions and created a PCB footprint.

[image: NES Interface]

Buying parts for a PS2 controller may be a bit easier, as it is not as old as NES. Just look for a broken PS2 or even some kind of adaptors and salvage connectors from them.

Here's an adapter for PS2:

[image]

Comment: hmm, interesting ideas. When you said "splitter adapter" you meant an actual part, not scavanged? The idea given by a person above of cutting the wires and soldering a new connector is very reasonable but I have not tried it. Connection a 9-pin 15-pin pin (DE or DA connectors) should do the trick. I did cut the wire of my PS2 dual shock controller and found some VERY fine thin wires inside.

Comment: @quantum231 The splitter adapter is shown in the second photo. You still have to break the thing apart and get the connectors out, but an adapter is likely to be much cheaper than buying a (broken) console.

Comment: Another possibility is to contact people who repair these gaming consoles.  They may have access to spare parts.  They may have partially cannibalized units.